# Every ID column must have 2 records that meet 2 values in another column

Tags: python, pandas

Each PatientID must have one record that is "Admit" *AND* one record that is "Discharge", nothing more nothing less.

In this table, for example, PatientID 152096 needs to go.

| PatientID | EventType |
| --- | --- |
| 25173 | Admit |
| 25173 | Discharge |
| 25174 | Admit |
| 25174 | Discharge |
| 152096 | Admit |
| 152096 | Admit |

I have got to this point by using

```
dfGrouped.groupby('PatientID').filter(lambda x: len(x) == 2)
```

I'm wondering if I should combine the PatientID into a single row first then check, or just check at this point.

Comment: Your table is better than an image, however please check [How to make pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples), that helps others helping you.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to filter by the two specific values:

```
m = df.groupby('PatientID')['EventType'].agg(set).eq({'Admit', 'Discharge'})

out = df[df['PatientID'].isin(m[m].index)]
```

If a number of 2 different Events is fine:

```
df.groupby('PatientID')['EventType'].nunique().eq(2)

out = df[df['PatientID'].isin(m[m].index)]
```

or:

```
out = df[df.groupby('PatientID')['EventType'].transform('nunique').eq(2)]
```

output:

```
   PatientID  EventType
0      25173      Admit
1      25173  Discharge
2      25174      Admit
3      25174  Discharge
```